# xfce4 / 16.04 Chrome sends so many inhibit messages, screen never sleeps

Tags: google-chrome, power-management, xfce

by running `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon --debug` in a terminal window, I can see why my screen never sleeps: Chrome (beta) is sending 
many inhibit messages, nested even. Some are not turned off via 'UnHibit'.

For example: as soon as chrome starts:

```
Inhibit send application name=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable reason=WebRTC has active PeerConnections sender=:1.202
```

Opening gmail seems to generate this WebRTC message too.
There is no unhibit message, ever.

Some of these reasons shouldn't stop screen blanking, but xfce4-power-manager stops all power management activities when it receives an inhibit message.

Can I stop Chrome from doing this, or set xfce4-power-manager to ignore inhibit messages from Chrome?

I can't find a chrome setting for this. I see this with Chrome stable and beta. The version of Chromium in the Ubuntu repositories is v53 and does not have this problem.

Comment: This went away.

Comment: I don't think this is fixed can you verify on the link given in this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451413/3285

Comment: I don't use xfce at the moment, I'm on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You're right, I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and still have the problem, uBlock stops it. I added a new question and will post what I learn there https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051688/how-to-stop-chrome-from-making-suspend-inhibits